# Kendo Ui CSS and JS files requirements

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I have a Vb.net MVC application that utilises Kendo UI (in the Bootstrap theme). I was told I had too many/conflicting css and js files declared but I'm struggling to figure out what my minimum requirements are. I'm also aware I may have some in the wrong order. I tried to fix this but have now managed to cause all dropdowns to display object [object] instead of the selected value.

I have the following declared...

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.mobile.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.112/jszip.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.mobile.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

Any help appreciated as I have no backup of the file before I started 'messing' and now do not know what was there originally and in which order. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the help you need is here : http://www.telerik.com/blogs/which-css-files-to-use-in-your-kendo-ui-project

After reading the article, I am still not sure that if you use kendo.mobile, you still need kendo.common for the css and kendo.all.min for the js if your application is also desktop.